# jquery autocomplete with dynamic resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

i have a function, let's call it `getUsers()`. this function do an ajax call and generate array list of users. this array will be use in jQuery autocomplete as the source. so it could be like:

```
var users = getUsers();
$("#elm_id").autocomplete({
  source: users
});
```

that actually what my code looks like, and that code is failed because i think the autocomplete is called before the XHR isn't finished yet. so, how do i make a callback for that autocomplete, so that the autocomplete will be executed after `success` callback of the `$.ajax` and this really should be done outside of the `getUsers()` function.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$.when( $.ajax( "test.php" ) ).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {

    $("#elm_id").autocomplete({
      source: data
    });
});
```

source [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)